# Open XML 2.5 retrieve cell style information

Tags: c#, excel, openxml-sdk

I'm trying to retrieve the cell contents, text formatting (bold, italic, font-family and font-size) and border formatting (line type, line weight, line color) for a range of cells using C# and Open XML 2.5.

I've found plenty of examples for reading the raw cell contents be it numeric or looking up text strings from the SharedStringTable. What I can't find is an example showing how to retrieve the formatting information for a given cell and I'm unsure where to start.

Would anyone by chance have a complete example of this for a single cell?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have it already, I would suggest you download [Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivity Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425)

open the file you want the cell information for and reflect the code.  The values you want should be in "/xl/Styles.xml" section of the workbook. If you want each individual cells information, follow the path to the "x:row" nodes where you can get the StyleIndex of the cell which maps to a set style (either auto generated or your own custom one)

Path to the row should be workbook >> worksheet>> sheetdata >> row

Also have a look at [Formatting Excel Values](http://lateral8.com/articles/2010/6/11/openxml-sdk-20-formatting-excel-values.aspx)

HTH